# Using a cookie with Indy

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, session-cookies, indy

I'm trying to get data from a site using the Indy components. (This is in Delphi 7 but happy to use anything that works.)

If you go into a normal browser and put in the path:
http://inventory.data.xyz.com/provide_data.aspx?ID=41100&Mixed=no?fc=true&lang=en
it makes you tick a disclaimer before redirecting you to the actual site. This creates a cookie, which if I look at it in Firefox is like this:
http://inventory.data.xyz.com
Name: ASP.NET_SessionId
Content: vm4l0w033cdng5mevz5bkzzq
Path: /
Send For: Any type of connection
Expires: At end of session

I can't get through the disclaimer part using programming but I thought if I manually sign the disclaimer, I can then enter the details of the cookie into my code and connect directly to the data page. I have tried to do this with the code below but it only returns the html for the disclaimer page which tends to imply it's not using the cookie data I've given it. What am I doing wrong?

```
procedure TfmMain.GetWebpageData;
var
  http: TIdHTTP;
  cookie: TIdCookieManager;
  sResponse: String;
begin
  try
    http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    http.AllowCookies := True;
    http.HandleRedirects := True;
    cookie := TIdCookieManager.Create(nil);
    cookie.AddCookie('ASP.NET_SessionId=vm4l0w033cdng5mevz5bkzzq', 'inventory.data.xyz.com');
    http.CookieManager := cookie;

    sResponse := http.Get('http://inventory.data.xyz.com/provide_data.aspx?ID=41100&Mixed=no?fc=true&lang=en');
    ShowMessage(sResponse);  // returns text of disclaimer
  except

  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not provided a real URL, I can only speculate, but chances are that either the cookie value you are providing to `TIdCookieManager` is wrong or outdated by the time `TIdHTTP.Get()` tries to use it, or more likely `TIdCookieManager.AddCookie()` is rejecting the cookie outright (if the `TIdCookieManager.OnNewCookie` event is not triggered, then the cookie was not accepted).

Comment: OK, I've found the answer. I moved the project to DelphiXE and it all works fine. I was using Delphi 7 and one of the first Indy 10s which I read basically didn't work with cookies. This current version does what it says on the tin.